# Why is the color alpha flickering after coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine that fades in a black screen, repositions the objects and then fades back. The problem is that when it's supposed to be transparent again, it flickers.
It seems either my for loops are not exiting correctly or my coroutine is not finishing. I am trying to stop the coroutine and set the color to transparent to avoid the flicker, but it doesn't work. Here is the important code:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (isMiddleDialogueActive)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeIn());
    }

    if (isDialogueFinished)
    {
        StopCoroutine(FadeIn());
        foreground.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Debug.Log(foreground.color);
    }
}

IEnumerator FadeIn()
{
    for (float i = 0; i <= 1; i += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        foreground.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, i);
        yield return null;
    }

    playerRb.transform.position = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
    jaguarRb.transform.position = new Vector2(-xPos, yPos);
    platforms.transform.position = new Vector2(startPosX, startPosY);

    for (float i=1; i >= 0; i -= Time.deltaTime)
    {
        foreground.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, i);
        yield return null;
    }

    textManager.StartDialogue();
    isDialogueFinished = true;
}
```

Comment: Stopping the coroutine like that will not work, you need to stop the Coroutine returned by StartCoroutine.  That however is not the problem, since `isDialogueFinished` is being set to true which happens at the end of the routine.  Instead it is likely that `isMiddleDialogueActive` stays true and the coroutine is being started many times.  You can test that by setting `isMiddleDialogueActive` to false at the beginning of `FadeIn`.

Comment: I added another bool to make sure it doesn't enter the coroutine again, since ill be needing isMiddleDialogueActive later on. Same logic as you recommended, it worked perfectly, thanks!